# Is it possible to implement a function like the network tab of the Chrome verification function with javascript?

Tags: javascript, interceptor

You can use the CHROME validation function to check the HTTP request status.
I want to get a specific URL using javascript, what code do I need to write to achieve that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEaRA.png)

Comment: Verification? Validation function? What are you talking about?

Comment: I want to do the same thing as chrome Developer Tools

Comment: You cannot - not for arbitrary urls. Code inside a webpage is constrained by the same origin policy, unlike the devtools. You might want to have a look at the old [*Firebug* (lite) user script](https://getfirebug.com) for how to implement something similar to the devtools, though.